# Running an interactive shell script in python

Tags: python

I have a shell script which I execute manually like below

First it prints some message and then at the end asks for username:

```
>/x/y/somescript "a b c"

Please enter the credentials of the XXX administrator account to use...
NOTE: The account provided below must hold the XXXXX role.

Username:
```

then after I enter the username and press ENTER, it asks for Password

```
Password:
```

Soon after typing the password and press ENTER, it shows some desired output like below.

```
Following is the list of algorithm(s) available in the system
|  Algorithm Name |      Algorithm Type      | Key Size |  Status  |
|  SHA512withRSA  |   SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM    |    -     | enabled  |
|   SHA1withDSA   |   SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM    |    -     | disabled |
|  SHA256withDSA  |   SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM    |    -     | disabled |
|  SHA512withDSA  |   SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM    |    -     | disabled |
| SHA256withECDSA |   SIGNATURE_ALGORITHM    |    -     | enabled  |
```

Now I wanted o automate this in python. I thought pexpect would be a good tool for the same. I have written a small script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import pexpect

localcmd='/x/y/some_script "a b c"'

def localOutput(command):
        child = pexpect.spawn (command)
        child.expect ('Username: ')
        child.sendline ('administrator')
        child.expect ('Password: ')
        child.sendline ('Testpassw0rd')
        return child.before   # Print the result of the ls command.

localout=localOutput(localcmd)

print "output from local query: \n "+localout # print out the result
```

But when I execute the script it always says:

```
# python final.py
output from local query:
 administrator
```

Can anybody tell me where I am wrong exactly?

Comment: insert `child.expect(pexpect.EOF)` before `return child.before`

Comment: Not working after adding the statement but there is a different output now. Says invalid user. But when executed manually the username and password it works. But not in the python script.

Comment: create a dummy `child.py` script that emulates the output of `somescript`, run it using `pexpect` and inspect username, password in it.

Comment: Sorry ..it works now I gave a wrong password. Thanks a lot. Please put an answer so that I will accept that. Also please care to explain why is that required here?

Answer (score 0):

Your function may return prematurely before `pexpect` has read all the output from the child process. You need to add `child.expect(pexpect.EOF)` so that all the output (perhaps until some buffer is full) is read.

A simpler option is to use [`pexpect.run()` function](https://pexpect.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/pexpect.html#pexpect.run):

```
output, status = pexpect.runu(command, withexitstatus=1,
                              events={'Username:': 'administrator\n',
                                      'Password:': 'Testpassw0rd\n'})
```

There might be issues if the command generates large output or takes too long (`timeout` parameter).