# python pexpect dnf upgrade automation

Tags: python, automation, pexpect

I am trying to write a Python script that automates running 'dnf upgrade' on Fedora. The same process should be useful on other Linux platforms like Debian as well.

To handle the prompts for the upgrade process, I am using the Python module 'pexpect'. I need to spawn the command 'sudo dnf upgrade' then enter a password if the 'Password:' prompt appears, then test for the '[y/N]' prompt and submit a 'Y' for that, and finally, if no '[y/N]' option appears, exit with a message that "No updates are available".

Here is the script I have written so far, but it seems to fail at the '[y/N]' test if there are no updates. I am not sure what I have to do to continue parsing the output.

```
import time
import pexpect

up = pexpect.spawn('sudo dnf update')

if up.expect(['(?i)password.*']) == 0:
    up.sendline('crazyhardpassword')
    time.sleep(2)
else:
    print("Permissions already elevated...")

if up.expect(['.*\[y/N\].*']) == 0:
    up.sendline('Y')
    time.sleep(2)
else:
    print("No upgrade approval prompt displayed!")

if up.expect(['(?i)^nothing.*\r\nComplete!.*']) == 0:
    print("No updates available...")
else:
    raise AssertionError("Upgrade request failed!!!")
```

Any suggestions on successfully executing the script whether or not there are updates?

Thank you.

Comment: 1- don't hardcode the sudo password inside your script. Add dnf-update script to sudoers instead (for Ubuntu: [How to run sudo command with no password?](https://askubuntu.com/q/192050/3712)) 2- to handle non-password prompts, if the questions are unique (don't depend on the order), you could use `events` parameter [Running an interactive shell script in python](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31337924/4279)

Comment: Thank you, @jfs , for the answer. I assume in the second link, I was supposed to see 'child.expect(pexpect.EOF)' and I tried adding that to the end of the script, but it is still does not work for the case when there are no updates to install. It seems to work when there are updates to install.

Comment: no, you should see an example of passing `events` parameter to `pexpect.run()`¶ It is not an answer, it is a comment.